# Find the pH of an amphiprotic salt dissolved in water at room temperature

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base, equilibrium

Let's say I have a polyprotic acid $\ce{H2A}$ with the following properties:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{H2A &<=> HA- + H+} & K_1 &= 1\cdot 10^{-1}\\
\ce{HA- &<=> A^2-+ H+} &  K_2 &= 1\cdot 10^{-4}     
\end{align}
$$

Now a 0.5 M solution of $\ce{HA-}$ is prepared; what will be the $\mathrm{pH}$ of the solution?

My textbook (and many other sources) says it should be

$$\frac{\mathrm{p}K_1 + \mathrm{p}K_2}{2}$$

which sounds a little counterintuitive to me.

First of all, it implies that the $\mathrm{pH}$ is independent of the concentration of $\ce{HA-}$ present.

Also, if $1/\mathrm{p}K_1 > \mathrm{p}K_2$, then $\ce{HA-}$ should have the tendency to accept a $\ce{H+}$ more than it has of losing one, then why is the $\mathrm{pH}$ exactly partway between $\mathrm{p}K_1$ and $\mathrm{p}K_2$?

Comment: To clear up one point, what you have is a buffer solution. Indeed the pH of the buffer solution does not depend on the concentration. However a buffer solution has a *buffer capacity* that is its resistance to change pH when acid or base is added. The lower the concentration of the amphiprotic salt, the lower the buffer capacity.

Comment: $\ce{pH} = \dfrac{\ce{pK_1 + pK_2}}{2}$ if only if ${\ce{[HA-] >> K_1}}$

Answer (score 8):

$$\begin{align}
\mathrm pH &=\mathrm
pK_\mathrm{a1}+\log \frac {[\ce{HA-}]} {[\ce{H2A}]} \\
\mathrm pH &=\mathrm pK_\mathrm{a2}+\log \frac {[\ce{A^2-}]} {[\ce{HA-}]} \\
\mathrm pH &=\frac{\mathrm pK_\mathrm{a1} + pK_\mathrm{a2} +\log \frac {[\ce{A^2-}]} {[\ce{H2A}]}} {2}\\
\end{align}$$

The last equation is the sum of the equation sides, divided by 2.

We can consider for expected acidic $\mathrm pH$, that we can neglect water dissociation and suppose $\ce{H+}$ is produced and consumed by these 2 reactions:
$$\begin{align}
\ce{HA- + H+ &<=> H2A} \\
\ce{HA-  &<=> H+ + A^2-} \\
\end{align}$$

Therefore:

$$\begin{align}
[\ce{H}]&={[\ce{A^2-}]}-{[\ce{H2A}]} \\
\mathrm pH &=\frac{\mathrm pK_\mathrm{a1} + \mathrm pK_\mathrm{a2} +\log \frac {[\ce{H2A}] + [\ce{H+}] } {[\ce{H2A}]}} {2}\\
\mathrm pH &=\frac{\mathrm pK_\mathrm{a1} + \mathrm pK_\mathrm{a2} +\log \left( 1 + \frac { [\ce{H+}] } {[\ce{H2A}]}\right)}  {2}\\
K_\mathrm{1a}&=\ce{[H+][HA-] /[H2A]} \\
\ce{[H2A]}&=\ce{[H+][HA-]} /K_\mathrm{1a}\\
\mathrm pH &=\frac{\mathrm pK_\mathrm{a1} + \mathrm pK_\mathrm{a2} +\log \left( 1 + \frac { K_\mathrm{1a}} {[\ce{HA-}]}\right)}  {2}\\
\end{align}$$

Therefore, if $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a1}$ is high enough, i.e. if $\ce{H2A}$ is rather a weak acid,
the simplified formula $\mathrm{p}H=(\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a1} + \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a2})/2$ is right enough.

If $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a1}=\ce{[HA-]}$, the $\mathrm{p}H$ correction is cca $+0.15 = \log (2)/2$

And then we can use this equation to  iterative corrections, with $\ce{[MHA]}$ being concentration of the used acidic  salt. The fraction is the classical formula to calculate ion fraction.

$$\ce{[HA-]}=\ce{[MHA]} \cdot \small
\frac {K_\mathrm{a1}.\ce{[H+]}}
{[\ce{H}]^2+K_\mathrm{a1} \cdot \ce{[H+]} + K_\mathrm{a1} \cdot K_\mathrm{a2}} $$

$$\frac {K_\mathrm{a1}}{\ce{[HA-]}}=
\frac {[\ce{H}]^2+K_\mathrm{a1} \cdot \ce{[H+]} + K_\mathrm{a1} \cdot K_\mathrm{a2}}
{\ce{[MHA]} \cdot \small
\ce{[H+]}}$$

For particular calculation, the first shoot is taking $\mathrm pH$ from the simplified  formula:

$$\begin{align}
\mathrm pH &=\frac{\mathrm pK_\mathrm{a1} + \mathrm pK_\mathrm{a2}}{2}=(1+4)/2=2.5 \\
\end{align}$$

I have realized, the direction of iterations must be reversed, as the formulas lead to divergence. ( It is known mathemathical problem to choose the right iteration with the small derivative $\mathrm{d}f(x)/\mathrm{d}x$.

The simplified equation at the bottom of the post expects  not too acidic or alkaline $\mathrm pH$. It supposes the equilibrium reactions affecting
 $[\ce{H}]$ do not significantly affect ratio of concentrations  $$\frac {[\ce{A^2-}]}{[\ce{H2A}]}$$

As the $\mathrm pH$ is near the both $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$, it is quite a fair assumption for most cases.

$$\begin{align}
\ce{2 HA- &<=> H2A + A^2-} \\
\frac {[\ce{H2A}]} {[\ce{HA-}]} &=\frac {[\ce{A^2-}]} {[\ce{HA-}]}\\
 [\ce{H2A}] &= [\ce{A^2-}] \\
\mathrm pH &=\frac{\mathrm pK_\mathrm{a1} + \mathrm pK_\mathrm{a2}}{2}  \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: In step three how did you took the average of both pH values to get the final pH?

Comment: It is formally an average, but of the same values. It was pure mathematical trick of equivalent operations over equations. You can add or multiply both sides by the same nonzero value, even if the expressions with the same value are not the same. I summed left sides, right sides and divided by 2.

Comment: But you assumed that pH is independently defined by the first two equations. The real pH is dependent on both of these pK values. Hence, the first and second equation is true if only the first and second ionizations respectively are considered.

Comment: The beginning is exact. pH must obey simultaneously both first equations. pH from both equations are equal.

Comment: I think there is a factor two missing in line 4.

Comment: No, It is intentional.It is  not aimed to be an exact ion balance, including water product.  The idea is H is created HA->A and consumed HA->H2A. Unless there is mistake in this idea.

Answer (score 3):

Brilliant question, and brilliant comment by MaxW, that deserves a non-textbook answer.

> First of all, it implies that the pH is independent of the concentration of HA− present.

Yes, like a buffer.

> Also, if 1/pK1>pK2, then HA− should have the tendency to accept a H+ more than it has of losing one, then why is the pH exactly partway between pK1 and pK2?

The tendency to accept an H+ (as expressed in the ratio of conjugate acid and conjugate base) depends both on the pH and the pKa. If the pH were neutral, we could not have both reactions be at equilibrium. We need a pH that is midway between the pKa values.

Let's treat this as a buffer:

$$\ce{H2A <=> 2 H+ + A^2-}$$

with $K_{a12} = K_{a1} * K_{a2}.$

Let's check out what happens when $\ce{[H2A] = [A^2-]}$. Inserting the concentrations and taking the negative logarithm, we get:

$$\ce{[H2A]} \times K_{a12} = \ce{[H+]^2 \times [A^2-]}$$

$$ \mathrm{pK_{a12} = pK_{a1} + pK_{a2} = 2 pH}$$

$$ \mathrm{pH = \frac{pK_{a1} + pK_{a2}}{2}}$$

> So why is $\ce{[H2A] = [A^2-]}$?

Well, it works. If you calculate $\ce{[H2A]}$ from pH and $\ce{[HA-]}$, and then calculate $\ce{[A^2-]}$ from pH and $\ce{[HA-]}$, you get the same answer.

If we estimate the pH as:
$$ \ce{[H+]} \overset{!}{=} \sqrt{\mathrm K_{a1} \times K_{a2}} $$

For $\ce{[H2A]}$, we get:
$$\ce{[H2A]} \times K_{a1} = \ce{[H+] \times [AH^-]}$$

$$\ce{[H2A]}  = \frac{\ce{[H+]} \times \ce{[AH^-]}}{\mathrm K_{a1}} = \ce{[AH^-]} \times \sqrt{ \frac{\mathrm K_{a2}}{\mathrm K_{a1}}}$$

And for $\ce{[A^2-]}$, we get:
$$\ce{[AH^-]} \times \mathrm{K_{a2}} = \ce{[H+] \times \ce{[A^2-]}}$$

$$\ce{[A^2-]}  = \frac{\mathrm{K_{a2}} \times \ce{[AH^-]}}{\ce{[H+]}} = \ce{[AH^-]} \times \sqrt{ \frac{\mathrm K_{a2}}{\mathrm K_{a1}}}$$

This is a bit of a circular argument, but it is fine because there is always just one equilibrium state for a system. So if you happen to find it and can show everything is at equilibrium, it must be correct.

**How is this different from a buffer?**

The buffer capacity (compared to a conventional 1:1 buffer with a pKa equal to the desired pH) is miserable because the main species is $\ce{HA-}$. You would be able to change the concentration ratio of diprotic acid and the dianion by adding minimal amount of strong acids or base, with a large effect on the pH.

Comment: The exercise you left for the readers was essentially my question, as I also prepared a solution with only $HA^-$ and then questioned why [$H_2A$] is the same as [$A^2-$] as their reactions have a different equilibrium constant.

Comment: Ok I’ll add that bit.

Comment: Huh? Since the main species is $\ce{HA-}$ the buffer capacity is at a maximum. See this figure for [oxalic acid](http://www.scielo.org.mx/img/revistas/jmcs/v57n4/a1f8.jpg) which is from this [paper](http://www.scielo.org.mx/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S1870-249X2013000400001).

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking of a different reference point. A 1:1 buffer of H2A and HA- would have better buffer capacity, and a 1:1 buffer of HA- and A(2-) would have better buffer capacity. Of course, they would buffer at a different pH. Also, finding a buffer with a pKa at (pKa1 + pKa2)/2 would be a better buffer as 1:1 buffer at the pH in question.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. A diprotic acid could be used for a buffer at two pH's. When $\ce{[H2A] = [HA-]}$ and $\ce{[HA-] = [A^{2-}]}$

Comment: @MaxW  But if pKa difference is too big, it has low buffering capacity, as both buffer systems would be far from their pKa optimum. It would rather lay at the capacity minimum. In some sense, it is like mixture of a salt of a moderately strong acid and of a weak acid. Neither of them is particularly good buffer.

Comment: @KarstenTheis "If you calculate $\ce{[H2A]}$ from pH and $\ce{[HA-]}$, and then calculate $\ce{[A^2-]}$ from pH and $\ce{[HA-]}$, you get the same answer." Can you help to understand it by writing the solution .Thanks .

Comment: @AdnanAL-Amleh I added the calculation. If you like numbers better than symbols, you can try the example Poutnik gave in another answer.

Answer (score 2):

I first found the derivation here
https://www.chembuddy.com/?left=pH-calculation&right=pH-amphiprotic-salt
but the hydrolysis was missing, i tried to derive with hydrolysis and got similar result just with $K_w$ added.

[image]

$k_{a1}$, $k_{a2}$ are first and second dissociation constants of the weak acid $\ce{H2A}$, $k_w$ is dissociation constant of water
I have followed equation $\ce{3->1->2}$  (second has the final concentrations boxed)
the upper concentrations are at $t=0$ and lowers are at $t=t_{eq}$

[image]

assuming $x, y << C$, $C=[\ce{HA-}]^\circ$ (initial concentration of $\ce{HA-}$)

[image]

the two are almost similar and $k_w$ can be neglected in many cases (example of $\ce{H3PO3}$ is at the site above, it can be proved by putting $k_a$ values of $\ce{H3PO3}$, for easy calculation, take
$pk_{a1}=2$ and $pk_{a2}=7$
and [$\ce{HA-}$] (0.001M will be good for a significant difference in pH) in either of the equations, in second $k_w$ has to be neglected),

the pH of 0.001 M $\ce{H2PO2-}$ ion must come around 5.2  (assuming third dissociation step is negligible) .
At $[\ce{HA-}] < 0.01M$  , difference in pH calculated by the above and calculated by
$pH=\frac{pK_{a1}+pK_{a2}}{2}$, increases significantly as $k_{a1}$ cannot be neglected.

$pH=\frac{pK_{a1}+pK_{a2}}{2}$ this can be derived by assuming $k_{a1} <<[\ce{HA-}]$ in the above equation. Everything is mentioned at the site

Comment: Please see the site's guidelines for typesetting. Your post is not very readable in its current state.

Comment: You can refer this link for how to write equations and chemical formulae on your regular keyboard using MathJax: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: thanks for pointing out and thank you for the edit