# Equivalence point pH derivation of a tribasic acid

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, equilibrium, ph, titration

Considering $\pu{100 mL} \ \pu{0.1 M} \ \ce{H3A}$ and $\pu{0.1 M} \ \ce{NaOH}$ titration curve:

[image: Titration Curve of a tribasic acid]

I understood the half equivalence points, but couldn't understand the reason why $\mathrm{pH} = \frac{1}{2}[\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a1} + \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a2}]$ at equivalence points.

So I tried to derive this and for that I did following:

$$\ce{H3A  -> H2A- + H+}  \quad \mathrm{}K_\mathrm{a1}$$

$$\ce{H2A-  -> HA^2- + H+}  \quad \mathrm{}K_\mathrm{a2}$$

$$\therefore \ \ce{H3A -> HA^2- + 2H+} \quad  K = \mathrm{}K_\mathrm{a1} \cdot \mathrm{}K_\mathrm{a2}$$

So, $\mathrm{}K_\mathrm{a1} \cdot \mathrm{}K_\mathrm{a2} = \frac{[\ce{HA^2-}][\ce{H+}]^2 }{[\ce{H3A}]}$.

This would give $\mathrm{pH} = \frac{1}{2}[\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a1} + \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a2}]$ but I don't know how $\ce{[H3A]}$ gets cancelled with $\ce{[HA^2-]}$.

Comment: Try to search the site, it was discussed several times. For eventual writing and formatting of chemical or mathematical formulas or equations, see how to use  [MathJax](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here/88)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @Poutnik

Comment: Write down ion balance at the partial  equivalence and consider conditions leading to approximation where concentrations of H3A and HA^2- are equal.

Comment: See [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/114504/how-accurately-does-pka1-pka2-2-estimate-the-ph-of-an-amphoteric-salt) and [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/114488/find-the-ph-of-an-amphiprotic-salt-dissolved-in-water-at-room-temperature)  Qs/As