# How to calculate the pH of solutions of amphoteric salts?

Tags: acid-base, ph, salt

I've been trying to understand how to calculate **the pH of solutions of amphoteric salts**, but I just can't figure it out. So, I've seen that it is commonly explained like this (example for a solution of NaH2PO4):

The salt completely dissociates like so 
$\ce{NaH2PO4}$-->$\ce{Na+}$ + $\ce{H2PO4-}$

Then the H2PO4- ion reacts with water to form HPO4 2- and H3O+.  (reaction 1)
$\ce{H2PO4-}$ + $\ce{H2O}$ <=> $\ce{HPO4  2-}$ + $\ce{H3O+}$ _______   $\ce{Ka2=6.2 x 10^{-8}}$

And then it reacts with H3O+ to form H3PO4 and H2O.  (reaction 2)
$\ce{H2PO4-}$ + $\ce{H3O+}$ <=> $\ce{H3PO4}$ + $\ce{H2O}$   ________   $\ce{K=Ka1^{-1}, Ka1=7.52*10^{-3}}$

**The autoionization of water is negligible.**

Now, I imagine this process like this:
The concentration of the $\ce{H2PO4-}$ ion in the first reaction is equal to the concentration of the salt in the solution because the salt dissociates completely. As it reacts with $\ce{H2O}$ to form $\ce{HPO4 2-}$ and $\ce{H3O+}$ (reaction 1), its concentration decreases for a certain value of x. The equilibrium concentration of $\ce{H3O+}$ and $\ce{HPO4 2-}$ **in this reaction** are the same and equal x. The equilibrium concentration of $\ce{H2PO4-}$ is equal to the concentration of the salt minus x.

$\ce{[H2PO4-]1=c(salt)-x}$
$\ce{[H3O+]1=x}$
$\ce{[HPO4 2-]=x}$

$\ce{Ka2=\frac{[H3O+]1*[HPO4 2-] }{[H2PO4-]1}}$

Then, what is left of the $\ce{H2PO4-}$, that is the equilibrium concentration of $\ce{H2PO4-}$ from the first reaction reacts with the equilibrium concentration of  $\ce{H3O+}$ from the first reaction to form $\ce{H3PO4}$ and $\ce{H2O}$. The concentrations of $\ce{H2PO4-}$ and $\ce{H3O+}$ decrease for a certain value of y. So, in the equilibrium of this reaction, reaction 2, the equilibirum concentration of $\ce{H3PO4}$ will equal to y.

$\ce{[H2PO4-]2=[H2PO4-]1-y=c(salt)-x-y}$
$\ce{[H3O+]2=[H3O+]1-y=x-y}$
$\ce{[H3PO4]=y}$

$\ce{Ka1^{-1}=\frac{[H3PO4] }{[H2PO4-]2*[H3O+]2}}$

So the final concentration of $\ce{H3O+}$ is equal to the concentration of $\ce{H3O+}$ in the equilibrium of the second reaction.

$\ce{[H3O+]final=[H3O+]2}$

We can see that the final concentration of $\ce{H3O+}$ is equal to x-y. Because $\ce{[HPO4 2-]=x}$ and $\ce{[H3PO4]=y}$, we write:

$\ce{[H3O+]final=[HPO4 2-]-[H3PO4]}$

We can express $\ce{[HPO4 2-]}$ and $\ce{[H3PO4]}$ using the equilibrium constants, concentrations of $\ce{H3O+}$ and $\ce{H2PO4-}$.

$\ce{[H3O+]final=\frac{Ka2*[H2PO4-]1 }{[H3O+]1}-\frac{[H2PO4-]2*[H3O+]final }{Ka1}}$

If we assume that the initial concentration of $\ce{H2PO4-}$ is so large that the change of x and y are negligible, we can write that:

$\ce{[H2PO4-]2=[H2PO4-]1=c(salt)}$

If we assume that the concentration of $\ce{H3O+}$ is large enough so that the change of y is negligible, we can write:

$\ce{[H3O+]final=[H3O+]1}$

With those assumptions we can get this commonly used expression for explaining this problem

$\ce{[H3O+]final=\frac{Ka2*c(salt)}{[H3O+]final}-\frac{c(salt)*[H3O+]final }{Ka1}}$

and with a little bit of rearranging, we get this expression:

$\ce{[H3O+]final=\sqrt{\frac{Ka2 * c(salt)}{1+\frac{c(salt)}{Ka1}}}}$

What I don't understand is the fact that we were able to get the last equation because we assumed that the final concentration of $\ce{H3O+}$ ions **is equal** to their concentration in the equilibrium of the first reaction. But at the beginning, when we established the first equation for the final concentration of $\ce{H3O+}$, we assumed that the concentrations of $\ce{H3O+}$ ions in the equilibrium of the first and second(final) reaction **aren't equal**. If in the end we assumed they are equal, why can't we calculate the pH just using the first reaction? That way the $\ce{H2PO4-}$ wouldn't be treated as an amphoteric, which obviously isn't correct, so I'm wondering what is wrong in my approach?

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/114488/find-the-ph-of-an-amphiprotic-salt-dissolved-in-water-at-room-temperature