# Find the pH of a solution obtained by mixing 100 ml 0.1m Na3PO4 and 100 ml 0.1 M NaH2PO4. Given that H3PO4: [Κα₁ = 10^-4, Κα₂ = 10^-7, Каз = 10^-11]

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium, solutions, ph, concentration

So, my query is that since NaH2PO4 is a weak acid, and Na3PO4 is a basic salt, wouldn't they react? Another theory was that since NaH2PO4 is a weak acid and Na3PO4 is a salt of strong acid and NaH2PO4, so they would form a buffer. So, I thought Henderson-Hasselbalch equation would work.

therefore, pH = pKa2 + log 1

pH = 7?

Neither does this answer make sense nor does it match with the textbook answer of 9(assuming the textbook is correct). So it would be much appreciated, if someone could clear this up for me, thank you.

Comment: The solution mix is equivalent to 200 mL 0.1 M Na2HPO4. Both cases contain the same concentrations of ions, reaching the same equilibrium from different starting points.

Comment: A good question title should be simple, unique, resembling a magazine article headline or a book title. It should be in plain text, summarizing the topic, optionally formulated as a question. It should  avoid being a click bait, saying too much or too little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is simply a $0.1$ M solution of $\ce{Na2HPO4}$. And its pH is the average value of $p\pu{\mathrm{K}_{a2}}$ and $p\pu{\mathrm{K}_{a3}}$, which is $\frac{7+11}{2} = 9$.

Comment: I understand your solution but could you explain the logic behind taking an average of pKa2 and pKa3? That's kind of where my deficiency is.

Comment: See the [CH SE Post](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/114488/find-the-ph-of-an-amphiprotic-salt-dissolved-in-water-at-room-temperature) or search using the string `site:stackexchange.com pH amphoteric salt solution` or `site:libretexts.org pH amphoteric salt solution`